# Вызов модального окна только в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: javascript

Прошу подправить код.
Дело в этом - "document.getElementById('l1overlay').style.display='block'"
Можно как-то заменить?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
document.write(


"$(function() {
          
            if (!$.cookie('hideModal')) {
          
            var delay_popup = 5000;
           setTimeout("document.getElementById('l1overlay').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
            }
           
            $.cookie('hideModal', true, {
            
                expires: 1,
                path: '/'
            });
        });"

);

}
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то потребуется, то вот так вот заработало.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {



 $(function() {
            
            if (!$.cookie('hideModal')) {
           
            var delay_popup = 1000;
           setTimeout("document.getElementById('l1overlay').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
            }
           
            $.cookie('hideModal', true, {
            
                expires: 0,
                path: '/'
            });
        });


}
  
</script>
```